# Indeterminate progress bar with Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am writing program for Raspberry Pi that will show indeterminate progress while user waiting. The program will start automatically and will be killed by another shell script.

Here is what I have at the moment. It works, but I feel that it is not perfect. I will be changing this code frequently after users will give their feedback.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PINS_NUMBER 8

void switchPin(int pin, int status, int timeout) {
  digitalWrite(pin, status);
  delay(timeout);
}

void switchLine(int pins[], int status) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < PINS_NUMBER; i++) {
    switchPin(pins[i], status, 200);
  }
}

int main(void){
  wiringPiSetup();

  int leds[PINS_NUMBER] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < PINS_NUMBER; i++) {
    pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  while(1) {
    switchLine(leds, LOW);
    switchLine(leds, HIGH);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to change the number of your pins?

Comment: There is a limited number of usable pins, so it might be increased but not significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming**

For first, your code looks good, it's not so hard to understand.

> It works, but I feel that it is not perfect.

There is no *perfect code*. A code is evolving, a code is changing. So, instead of chasing perfection, you should pursue such things like readability.

Your function names are a bit confusing. For example without knowing the body of the `switchLine` function it's hard to firgure out that it will change the state of several pins sequentially with some delay.

How about a `main()` function like the following?

```
int main() {
    struct PinLedMap connections = {{
        { 0, LED_0 }, { 1, LED_1 }, { 2, LED_2 }, { 3, LED_3 },
        { 4, LED_4 }, { 5, LED_5 }, { 6, LED_6 }, { 7, LED_7 }
    }};
    assignPinsToLeds(&connections);
    initialize();

    setDelayOfSequentialOperations(250);
    while(1) {
        turnLedsOnSequentially();
        turnLedsOffSequentially();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think that the code above is clear enough, and easy to understand.

**Responsibility**

I don't see the reason why do the `switchPin` function applies the delay? The `switchPin` function should switch the state of specified pin only. Applying delays between turning LEDs on or off is the responsibility of your `switchLine` function.

In my example the `turnLedsOnSequentially` and the `turnLedsOffSequentially` functions work as follows:

```
void setLedsSequentiallyTo(enum LedState state) {
    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_LEDS; ++index) {
        setLedTo(index, state);
        delay(_delayInMilliseconds);
    }
}    
void turnLedsOnSequentially() {
    setLedsSequentiallyTo(LED_ON);
}    
void turnLedsOffSequentially() {
    setLedsSequentiallyTo(LED_OFF);
}
```

**Complete code**

I took my example into pieces, so it contains a header file (`led_control.h`) and two source files (`led_control.c`, `main.c`). I've presented the `main.c` before, so I won't present it again.

*led_control.h*

```
#ifndef LED_CONTROL_H
#define LED_CONTROL_H

enum LedNumber {
    LED_0, LED_1, LED_2, LED_3, LED_4, LED_5, LED_6, LED_7,
    NUMBER_OF_LEDS
};
struct PinLedPair {
    int pinNumber;
    enum LedNumber ledNumber;
};
struct PinLedMap {
    struct PinLedPair elements[NUMBER_OF_LEDS];
};

void assignPinToLed(struct PinLedPair* connection);
void assignPinsToLeds(struct PinLedMap* connections);
void initialize();
void setDelayOfSequentialOperations(int delayInMilliseconds);
void turnLedOn(enum LedNumber ledNumber);
void turnLedOff(enum LedNumber ledNumber);
void turnLedsOnSequentially();
void turnLedsOffSequentially();

#endif /* LED_CONTROL_H */
```

*led_control.c*

```
#include "led_control.h"
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <assert.h>

int _leds[NUMBER_OF_LEDS] = { 0 };
int _delayInMilliseconds = 100;

enum LedState {
    LED_OFF = LOW, LED_ON = HIGH
};

void assignPinToLed(struct PinLedPair* connection) {
    assert(connection);
    _leds[connection->ledNumber] = connection->pinNumber;
    pinMode(connection->pinNumber, OUTPUT);
}
void assignPinsToLeds(struct PinLedMap* connections) {
    int index;
    assert(connections);
    for(index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_LEDS; ++index)
        assignPinToLed(&connections->elements[index]);
}

void initialize() {
    wiringPiSetup();
}
void setDelayOfSequentialOperations(int delayInMilliseconds) {
    _delayInMilliseconds = delayInMilliseconds;
}

void _setLedTo(enum LedNumber ledNumber, enum LedState state) {
    digitalWrite(_leds[ledNumber], state);
}
void turnLedOn(enum LedNumber ledNumber) {
    _setLedTo(ledNumber, LED_ON);
}
void turnLedOff(enum LedNumber ledNumber) {
    _setLedTo(ledNumber, LED_OFF);
}

void _setLedsSequentiallyTo(enum LedState state) {
    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_LEDS; ++index) {
        _setLedTo(index, state);
        delay(_delayInMilliseconds);
    }
}
void turnLedsOnSequentially() {
    _setLedsSequentiallyTo(LED_ON);
}
void turnLedsOffSequentially() {
    _setLedsSequentiallyTo(LED_OFF);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!